# SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estoy tratando de enviar un formulario en **PHP** para enviarlo a través del servidor de **Godaddy**, pero cuando lo envío me sale el error

```
<?php

$nombre           = $_POST['nombre'];
$email            = $_POST['email'];
$compania         = $_POST['compania'];
$telefono         = $_POST['telefono'];
$pais             = $_POST['pais'];
$videoconferencia = $_POST['videoconferencia'];


if ($nombre == '' || $email == '') {

    echo "<script>alert('Los campos marcados con * son obligatorios');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";

} else {

    require("includes/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->From = ("usuario@hosting.com"); //Correo creado en el hosting
    //$mail->FromName = $nombre; 
    $mail->AddAddress("usuario@gmail.com"); //Correo de gmail donde se quiere que llegue el correo
    // Dirección a la que llegaran los mensajes.

    // Aquí van los datos que apareceran en el correo que reciba

    //$mail->WordWrap = 50; 
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "";
    $mail->Body    = '<html><body><br />' . '<h2><font face="times new roman" color="#000000"><span><font face="times new roman" color="#00769f">Datos del cliente</h2></font>' . "<table style='border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px; border-color:#A5D7DF;'><tr><td><strong>Pais</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($nombre) . "</td><br/></tr>" . "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($email) . "</td></tr>" . "<tr><td><strong>Compañia:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($compania) . "</td></tr>" . "<tr><td><strong>Telefono:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($telefono) . "</td></tr>" . "<tr><td><strong>Estado / Pais:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($pais) . "</td></tr>" . "<tr><td><strong>Localidad/El cliente va a usar Videoconferencia proximamente:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($videoconferencia) . "</td></tr>" . '<tr><td></td></tr></table>' . "<br />";

    // Datos del servidor SMTP
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host     = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
    $mail->Username = "usuario@hosting.com"; //Correo creado en el hosting
    $mail->Password = "*******"; //Password
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Port     = 25;

    if ($mail->Send())
        echo "<script>alert('Formulario Enviado');location.href ='';</script>";
    else
        echo "<script>alert('Error al enviar el formulario');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";
}

?>
```

**Error:**

> SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused

Answer (score 1):

Yo tuve ese problema y me parece recordar que había que usar el puerto 25, pero fue hace mucho y no sé si las cosas habrán cambiado. Prueba con:

```
$mail -> Port = 25;
```

Comment: Llame al servidor de godaddy y me dijeron que tenia que usar el  SMTP relay-hosting.secureserver.net pero no se como realizar el codigo en php

Answer (score 0):

Prueba modificando el servidor smtp a utilizar:

```
$mail->Host     = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
```